# can not find gem files forked from github repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, rubygems, bundler

I am using rails v 3.2.12 and standard jQuery plyg-in as a gem. Now I need to make some changes in it, so I forked github repo to do what I need and then install the gem and use it, and the problem is in the last step. I write in my gemfile

```
  gem 'fullcalendar-rails', :git =>  'https://github.com/mitchenkod/fullcalendar-rails-kogdata.git'
```

bundle install succedded, but my application can't find gem files when I start in in browser on localhost.
It's weird, cause the gem is installed. I've notised, in ruby derictory

```
 C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1
```

the gem file are usualy copied in gem folder, but my gem file I saw in a bundler foder
so, the question is, how can I tell rail to find files there, or make bundler to put them in an another folder, thaks!

Comment: How are you starting your Rails app? Are you using `bundle exec rails server`?

Comment: no, I am using RubyMine, and for the, rails server is used, as I can see in console

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the Rails server is being started with Bundler. Git gems are handled a little differently than "real" gems, so they can't be installed into the standard gem directory.

If running on the command line, you can use "bundle exec rails server" to run under Bundler.

In RubyMine, there is a checkbox in the Run/Debug configuration on the [Bundler tab](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-rails.html#bundlerTab): "Run the script in the context of the bundle". This needs to be checked.